# How to let the user enter height and width in prestashop?

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have to make an online shop in prestashop and I need to know how I can let the user enter the height and width and then calculate the final price.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a module that do what do you need:

https://addons.prestashop.com/it/grandezze-unita-misura/18047-product-price-by-size.html

Comment: Thanks but doesn't have a free version or one that I can test?

Comment: Mmm... I guess that you can test on the addons, or PrestaShop Cloud... I don't know a free version, I'm sorry

Comment: Have you used the module? Can you tell me if I can customize from what inserted values ​​the price changes? Thanks!